# React Helmet for multiple pages

Tags: reactjs, react-helmet

My client wanted a React website but he wants each pages’ meta title and description “to be custom written so that when someone types in the company name, the sub tabs under home say About, Contact, etc with their own description”.

I’m finding little documentation and/or examples of using React Helmet with multiple pages. I have a Home.jsx file, About.jsx, etc. How would I get each page to have specific metadata with Helmet?

Thank you for any info!

I haven’t tried because I can’t see any documentation of my issue.

UPDATE:

I've implemented React Helmet and the titles have changed successfully so that when the user is on /about, the title is "About Us". When I check console, it shows the updated About meta name="description", but the about meta description does not show on Google when the user types in the company and looks at the about tab under the home page. Any reason why this would be happening? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your question is about changing document.title and meta tags, all react-helmet really does is [look at its children components, map those to objects, then update the DOM](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/blob/master/src/HelmetUtils.js#L380) (it's a little more complex, but that's the idea). So on non-root views, you would do something like this:

```js
const About = () => (
  <div>
    <Helmet>
      <title>About</title>
      <meta name="description" content="I am an about page" />
    </Helmet>
    {/* other About page content here */}
  </div>
)
```

Of course you could pull those strings in from config or wherever if you need to.

The problem you'll face though is what's actually rendered in the HTML (for SEO) — for that, you'll need server-side rendering. You can use the [server-side usage of react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet#server-usage), or pass a variable to the view engine or templating or whatever (depending on how the server is set up, assuming there is a server). If you're strictly serving static files (like from an S3 bucket), you'll need to look into [prerendering](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/pre-rendering-into-static-html-files/).

---

If your question is about building out menus based on user (client) provided data later on, you absolutely will need a server, and maybe a CMS.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help. I did exactly as you said and it changes the title and meta description when i check the console. but it doesnt update when someone types in the company name on google and checks the about tab. i'm hosting the static site on netlify and enabled prerendering, but still nothing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, I think a [headless website](https://www.algolia.com/blog/ux/what-is-a-headless-website-a-definition-and-examples/) would be a good approach for your case.

There are various ways to implement that, but using headless CMS like [Contentful](https://www.contentful.com/), [Prismic](https://prismic.io/), or [Sanity](https://www.sanity.io/), etc. is recommended.

Once you choose a headless CMS, then you can fetch the data from it using your favorite JavaScript Server-side rendering frameworks such as Next.js, Gatsby, Nuxt.js, or whatever through GraphQL queries.

If React Helmet is required, then you can choose a React-based framework like Gatsby or Next.js.

You can separate the workspaces based on the companies and then use the variables in your environment separately.

Initially, you need to have a custom React Helmet component that can be used globally.

You can import that component in your initial layout as a [HOC](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) and pass static props or similar ones to that component.

Answer (score 0):

install react-helmet-async

wrap App component inside  tag

will be imported into any page component where you want to implement the meta tags

Learning React Helmet!

...and other meta tag implementations.